# Import a formula from a spreadsheet cell into VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, I'm very sorry for my ignorance. I'm very bad at coding and I'll probably not understand sophisticated explanations, so please be patient.

What I'd like to do is to extract a formula from a cell in a spreadsheet and use it in a VBA code. Let's say, I have a cell (2, 1) which contains following text: "x^2-6*x+15".

Now, I'd like to write a function in VBA called "f" which calculates a result based on the value of the cell (2, 1). So, for example, if I wrote "=f(1)" it would write 10, but if I changed the formula in the cell (2, 1) to, let's say, "x^3-x^2+17", it would recalculate and write 17. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will give the `f`-function two arguments:

1. the cell containing the string-formula
2. the value of "x"

the code in a standard module:

```
Public Function f(rng As Range, v As Variant) As Variant
    Dim sFormula As String
    
    sFormula = Replace(rng.Value, "x", v)
    f = Evaluate(sFormula)
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! While the answer you provided didn't work for me, thanks to you, I came up with a code that uses "replace" to make it work. It looks like this, should anyone be interested:

`Function f(v As Double) As Double

Dim q As String
q = Cells(2, 1)
formula = Replace(q, "x", v)
f = Evaluate(formula)

End Function`